# Trouble with gstreamer, video playing with qt 5.10 application on Ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, video, qt, multimedia, gstreamer

New laptop, installed Ubuntu 16.04, everything was fine. Now I'm trying to play video with my qt app. 
Sadly, I get an error when doing it - for avi files this is what I get:

```
(myApp:2322): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_caps_copy: assertion 'GST_IS_CAPS (caps)' failed

(myApp:2322): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: /build/glib2.0-7ZsPUq/glib2.0-2.48.2/./gobject/gtype.c:4273: type id '0' is invalid

(myApp:2322): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: can't peek value table for type '<invalid>' which is not currently referenced
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

And for mp4 files I get:

```
(myApp:2189): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_caps_ref: assertion 'GST_CAPS_REFCOUNT_VALUE (caps) > 0' failed

(myApp:2189): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_caps_ref: assertion 'GST_CAPS_REFCOUNT_VALUE (caps) > 0' failed

(myApp:2189): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_caps_unref: assertion 'GST_CAPS_REFCOUNT_VALUE (caps) > 0' failed

(myApp:2189): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: /build/glib2.0-7ZsPUq/glib2.0-2.48.2/./gobject/gtype.c:4273: type id '0' is invalid

(myApp:2189): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: can't peek value table for type '<invalid>' which is not currently referenced
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I'm using qt 5.10, Ubuntu 16.04, tried multiple advice on how to solve this issue without any luck.
Ldd myApp | grep "gst*" on my app executeable outputs the following:

```
libgstreamer-0.10.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstreamer-0.10.so.0 (0x00007f41ae295000)
    libgstvideo-0.10.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstvideo-0.10.so.0 (0x00007f41adb14000)
    libgstapp-0.10.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstapp-0.10.so.0 (0x00007f41ad907000)
    libgstriff-0.10.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstriff-0.10.so.0 (0x00007f41ad6fa000)
    libgstpbutils-0.10.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstpbutils-0.10.so.0 (0x00007f41ad4d6000)
    libgstbase-0.10.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstbase-0.10.so.0 (0x00007f41a4b59000)
    libgstaudio-0.10.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstaudio-0.10.so.0 (0x00007f41a469e000)
    libgsttag-0.10.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsttag-0.10.so.0 (0x00007f41a4466000)
    libgsm.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsm.so.1 (0x00007f419f842000)
    libgstinterfaces-0.10.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstinterfaces-0.10.so.0 (0x00007f419cf48000)
    libgssapi_krb5.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgssapi_krb5.so.2 (0x00007f419c17f000)
```

Dpkg -l | grep "gst*" in the terminal gives

```
ii  gir1.2-click-0.4                            0.4.43+16.04.20170613-0ubuntu1                amd64        GIR bindings for Click package management library
ii  gir1.2-gst-plugins-bad-1.0                  1.8.3-1ubuntu0.2                              amd64        GObject introspection data for the GStreamer libraries from the "bad" set
ii  gir1.2-gst-plugins-base-1.0                 1.8.3-1ubuntu0.3                              amd64        GObject introspection data for the GStreamer Plugins Base library
ii  gir1.2-gstreamer-1.0                        1.8.3-1~ubuntu0.1                             amd64        GObject introspection data for the GStreamer library
ii  gir1.2-gtk-2.0                              2.24.30-1ubuntu1.16.04.2                      amd64        GTK+ graphical user interface library -- gir bindings
ii  gir1.2-gtk-3.0:amd64                        3.18.9-1ubuntu3.3                             amd64        GTK+ graphical user interface library -- gir bindings
ii  gir1.2-pango-1.0:amd64                      1.38.1-1                                      amd64        Layout and rendering of internationalized text - gir bindings
ii  gstreamer1.0-alsa:amd64                     1.8.3-1ubuntu0.3                              amd64        GStreamer plugin for ALSA
ii  gstreamer1.0-clutter-3.0                    3.0.18-1                                      amd64        Clutter PLugin for GStreamer 1.0
ii  gstreamer1.0-libav:amd64                    1.8.3-1ubuntu0.2                              amd64        libav plugin for GStreamer
ii  gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad:amd64              1.8.3-1ubuntu0.2                              amd64        GStreamer plugins from the "bad" set
ii  gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-faad:amd64         1.8.3-1ubuntu0.2                              amd64        GStreamer faad plugin from the "bad" set
ii  gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-videoparsers:amd64 1.8.3-1ubuntu0.2                              amd64        GStreamer videoparsers plugin from the "bad" set
ii  gstreamer1.0-plugins-base:amd64             1.8.3-1ubuntu0.3                              amd64        GStreamer plugins from the "base" set
ii  gstreamer1.0-plugins-base-apps              1.8.3-1ubuntu0.3                              amd64        GStreamer helper programs from the "base" set
ii  gstreamer1.0-plugins-good:amd64             1.8.3-1ubuntu0.4                              amd64        GStreamer plugins from the "good" set
ii  gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly:amd64             1.8.3-1ubuntu0.1                              amd64        GStreamer plugins from the "ugly" set
ii  gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly-amr:amd64         1.8.3-1ubuntu0.1                              amd64        GStreamer plugins from the "ugly" set
ii  gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio:amd64               1.8.3-1ubuntu0.4                              amd64        GStreamer plugin for PulseAudio
ii  gstreamer1.0-tools                          1.8.3-1~ubuntu0.1                             amd64        Tools for use with GStreamer
ii  gstreamer1.0-x:amd64                        1.8.3-1ubuntu0.3                              amd64        GStreamer plugins for X11 and Pango
ii  libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0:amd64         1.8.3-1ubuntu0.2                              amd64        GStreamer development files for libraries from the "bad" set
ii  libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-dev             1.8.3-1ubuntu0.2                              amd64        GStreamer development files for libraries from the "bad" set
ii  libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0:amd64       0.10.36-2ubuntu0.2                            amd64        GStreamer libraries from the "base" set
ii  libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:amd64        1.8.3-1ubuntu0.3                              amd64        GStreamer libraries from the "base" set
ii  libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev            1.8.3-1ubuntu0.3                              amd64        GStreamer development files for libraries from the "base" set
ii  libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-0:amd64        1.8.3-1ubuntu0.4                              amd64        GStreamer development files for libraries from the "good" set
ii  libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-dev            1.8.3-1ubuntu0.4                              amd64        GStreamer development files for libraries from the "good" set
ii  libgstreamer0.10-0:amd64                    0.10.36-1.5ubuntu1                            amd64        Core GStreamer libraries and elements
ii  libgstreamer1.0-0:amd64                     1.8.3-1~ubuntu0.1                             amd64        Core GStreamer libraries and elements
ii  libgstreamer1.0-dev                         1.8.3-1~ubuntu0.1                             amd64        GStreamer core development files
```

Gst-launch-1.0 --version output

```
gst-launch-1.0 version 1.14.0
GStreamer 1.14.0
Unknown package origin
```

An important side note - my app is running with no problem on other ubuntu 16.04 computers. I am able to open the same videos on this laptop using totem/vlc, but not with rhythmbox.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update - After a very long day, turns out that opencv lib was linked to gstreamer0.10, qt to 1.0. This did not work well obviously.
When compiling opencv with linking to gstreamer1.0, works ok.